# Regex to find non-keyword

Tags: c#, regex, match

I can use pattern like this to find key word:

```
//find keyword
line = @"abc class class_ def this gh static";
string Pattern;
MatchCollection M1;
Pattern = @"(?<![a-zA-Z0-9_])(class|function|static|this|return)(?![a-zA-Z0-9_])";
M1 = Regex.Matches(line, Pattern);
for (int i = 0; i < M1.Count; i++)
    output += M1[i].ToString() + '\n';
```

But how can I find non-keyword like `abc`,`class_`,`def`,`gh`

Comment: What have you tried and what does not work? Note that your regex is basically `\b(?:class|function|static|this|return)\b` (if you need to only deal with ASCII, use `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option with it).

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think RegEx is a good approach for this use case.

The keywords are bad to maintain and the pattern grows with the number of keywords and gets slower Compared to a `Contains()`.

Use a `string[]` `List<string>` or `HashSet<string>` for your keywords instead.

```
string line = @"abc class class_ def this gh static";
string[] keywords = { "class", "function", "static", "this", "return" };

string outputexclude = string.Join("\n", line.Split().Where(x => !keywords.Contains(x)));
string outputinclude = string.Join("\n", line.Split().Where(keywords.Contains));
```

Comment: thx, in my compiler I need to use `ToArray()` for successfully run